# send email with attachment in C

Tags: c, smtp

Hi Im writing a C program that sends some files to an email adress. I already made it send an email but i dont know how to send attachments, I googled it and the only thing I found out is that I have to send it to the smtp server after using the DATA\n command.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(1,2);
    WSADATA data;
    int error;
    error = WSAStartup(version,&data);   

    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    SOCKADDR_IN saddr;
    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_port = htons(25);
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("173.194.76.26");

    char Antwort[1000]; int len;
    error = connect(s,(SOCKADDR*)&saddr,sizeof(saddr));
    len = recv(s,Antwort,1000,0);
    printf("\n\n%s",Antwort);
        send(s,"HELO dieseitegibtsnicht.de\n",strlen("HELO dieseitegibtsnicht.de\n"),0);
    recv(s,Antwort,1000,0);
    printf("\n\n%s",Antwort);
        send(s,"MAIL FROM: <maxmustermann@gmail.com>\n",strlen("MAIL FROM: <maxmustermann@gmail.com>\n"),0);
    recv(s,Antwort,1000,0);
    printf("\n\n%s",Antwort);
        send(s,"RCPT TO: <CENSORED@gmail.com>\n",strlen("RCPT TO: <CENSORED@gmail.com>\n"),0);
    recv(s,Antwort,1000,0);
    printf("\n\n%s",Antwort);
        send(s,"DATA\n",strlen("DATA\n"),0);
    recv(s,Antwort,1000,0);
    printf("\n\%s",Antwort);
    char msg[300] = "TO: CENSORED@gmail.com\nFROM: maxmustermann@gmail.com\nSUBJECT: Irgendwas\nDas hier kann hier eh keiner lesen\r\n.\r\n";
        send(s,msg,strlen(msg),0);
    recv(s,Antwort,1000,0);
    printf("\n\n%s",Antwort);
        send(s,"QUIT\n",strlen("QUIT\n"),0);
    recv(s,Antwort,1000,0);
    printf("\n\n%s",Antwort);
}
```

Comment: Sending an attachment has nothing to do with the SMTP protocol, as the email and attachment are both part of the data you are sending. So indeed, it has to do with the DATA command. Just send valid email headers, which in this part would include a multipart MIME header.

Comment: Did you search the appropriate RFC? If so, what problem do you encounter?

Comment: Took a look at MIME and got it working now thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the library at https://sourceforge.net/projects/libquickmail/ which already does what you are trying to do.